# A2DP doesn't work with PC, but works with a phone

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I used [this project](https://github.com/nicokaiser/rpi-audio-receiver) to set up A2DP.

There is no problem with a `phone <-> rpi` connection.
However, my PC (elementary OS) is struggling to connect to Raspberry Pi 4. But even when it does connect there is no sound in output. I'm able to connect to Mi Bluetooth Speaker without any problem and play music. My PC succesfully recognizes Raspberry as audio output and sends audio. I did check with a `sudo hcidump -x -i hci0` that data arrive, but IDK what happens next.

dmesg:

```
[   13.733812] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.733892] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   13.733906] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.733931] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.733952] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.733983] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.749748] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   13.749766] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   13.749858] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   13.750162] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   13.895308] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.895314] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.895327] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.497453] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead
[  387.061261] input: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:33 as /devices/virtual/input/input0
[ 3030.987129] input: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:18 as /devices/virtual/input/input1
```

[alsa info.](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=9e05a54a67432723b38eaf251f499cc2175d48bd)

Comment: Works OK with phone and not with PC would suggest the problem is with the PC, Not the Pi. And as such the question is if it's a problem for Pi SE...

Comment: Just tested with my laptop and there is the same issue as with a PC